# switch value between column based pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
     Name  Age      City Gender Country
0     Jane   23     NaN      F    London
1  Melissa   45     Nan      F    France
2     John   35     Nan      M   Toronto
```

I want to switch value between column based on condition:

```
if Country equal to Toronto and London
```

I would like to have this output:

```
   Name  Age      City  Gender Country
0     Jane   23     London   F     NaN   
1  Melissa   45     NaN      F    France
2     John   35     Toronto  M     NaN
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to check the rows where `Country` contains London or Toronto, then set the City column to those values and use another loc statement to replace London and Toronto with Nan in the country column

```
df.loc[df['Country'].isin(['London', 'Toronto']), 'City'] = df['Country']
df.loc[df['Country'].isin(['London', 'Toronto']), 'Country'] = np.nan
```

output:

```
      Name  Age     City Gender Country
0     Jane   23   London      F     NaN
1  Melissa   45      NaN      F  France
2     John   35  Toronto      M     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
cities = ['London', 'Toronto']
df['City'] = np.where(
    df['Country'].isin(cities),
    df['Country'],
    df['City']
)
df['Country'] = np.where(
    df['Country'].isin(cities),
    np.nan,
    df['Country']
)
```

Results:

```
      Name  Age     City Gender Country
0     Jane   23   London      F     NaN
1  Melissa   45      NaN      F  France
2     John   35  Toronto      M     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cond = df['Country'].isin(['London', 'Toronto'])
df['City'].mask(cond, df['Country'], inplace = True)
df['Country'].mask(cond, np.nan, inplace = True)

      Name  Age     City Gender Country
0     Jane   23   London      F     NaN
1  Melissa   45      NaN      F  France
2     John   35  Toronto      M     NaN
```